# Ionic Framework JWT Post call not able to pass parameters

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, jwt

I am trying to make a POST webservice call in **ionic framework**. The server is able to recognise the token but is not reading the parameters. Below is my code

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $http, $state) {
    //console.log($window.localStorage);
    var token = $window.localStorage.getItem("token");

    $scope.onDuty = function () {
        $http.post(url, JSON.stringify({
            "status": "1",
            "latitude": "17",
            "longitude": "12"
        }), {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer" + token}}
        // {
        //     'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
        // }
        ).then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);  
        });
    };
});
```

Am I missing something here. Please help

Comment: Have you tried to pass an object instead of `JSON.stringify` result?

Comment: Yes. Still same response

Answer (score 0):

standard usage of **$http** does not need to use any **JSON.stringify**, second argument can be complex object. So remove **JSON.stringify** and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I tried doing that but still no luck